# Need help to quickly search iOS Property List (plist) for value?

Tags: objective-c, ios, plist, nsdictionary

I currently have a plist file in my iOS Project which is downloaded from the web when updates are available and it contains a list of news articles along with images.

The application caches the images on the iPhone for offline access, I am currently trying to write a function which will clean the cached files every so often.

Currently I have this code which looks in the Temp folder for images and then deletes them, however for each image found I would like it to check if the file name exists as a value in the plist stored as NSDictionary before deleting, however I am not sure of a quick method to search the NSDictionary without the need for a for statement.

Any tips would be great.

```
 NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:TMP error:nil];
    if (files == nil) {
        // error...
        NSLog(@"no files found");
    }

    for (NSString *file in files) {

        NSString *uniquePath = [TMP stringByAppendingPathComponent: file];
        if([file rangeOfString: @".png" options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", file);   


            if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: uniquePath error: NULL]  == YES)
                NSLog (@"Remove successful");
            else
                NSLog (@"Remove failed");

        }
    }
```

EDIT

I have currently added this not sure if its the best way to do it but it works.

```
 NSArray *newsArray = [self.newsData allValues];

 // Convert the Array into a string
 NSString *newsString = [newsArray description];

 // Perform Range Search.
 NSRange range;
 range = [newsString rangeOfString : filename];

 if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"The file exists in the plist %@", filename);
 } else {
     // Delete the file
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the array so that it only contains the objects you are interested in by using a `NSPredicate`, then quickly loop over the objects which you wish to delete. Like so:

```
NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:TMP error:nil];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] '.png'"];

NSArray *filteredArray = [files filteredArrayUsingPredicate:thePredicate];

for (NSString *file in filteredArray) {

    NSString *uniquePath = [TMP stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];

     if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: uniquePath error: NULL])
            NSLog (@"Remove successful");
     else
        NSLog (@"Remove failed");

}
```

This will mean that the for loop is only looping over objects you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for that I'm actually wanting to do a reverse search i.e. loop through image files on the device and then see if that file name exists in my plist as the plist will be replaced on each launch with a brand new version from the website.

Comment: I see, so you are filtering for .png to simply catch that the file is an image file and you still need to logic to check the plist?

Comment: I'm basically getting a dir list of a folder then for each physical image file (png) found on the disk I need to check if its file name still exists in the plist file

Comment: I see, well you just need to create a predicate for each iteration of the loop and then run it on an array of dictionaries returned from the plist, the predicate method evaluateWithObject will tell you if it is inside the plist or not, i'm heading out now but will update my answer when i return

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not care about the sequence of files in plist or folder and you obviously won't have duplication, use NSSet rather than NSArray and then use intersect method (intersectsSet:) to find intersection.